# having issue with the proof environment

Tags: amsthm, proof-package

I am using theorem, lemma,corollary, and proof environments with the following way.

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

All of them properly works excluding the proof. When I start a proof with

```
\begin{proof}
...
 \end{proof}
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua8bF.jpg) is what I see. If I use `\usepackage{amsthm}` to use proof, then it messes up the other environments and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1qeR.jpg) is what I get.

I am using the LaTeX `INFORMS Journal on Computing Style Files` template provided in this [website](https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files). Then, I open the template and add the `\newtheorem`commands as shown above. If I put the following code block and compile, I receive the error.

```
\begin{theorem}
Here is my theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
This is the lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
this is the proof.
\end{proof}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable code reproducing the problem. It is impossible to give an answer/help with only these elements.

Comment: @Bernard I added some extra information. I believe that it is related to the template that I am using.

Comment: `amsthm` provides a `proof` so you don't need to define it.

Comment: @Sigur As I mentioned in the original post, when I use ```amsthm ```, it creates more problem. Of course, when I use that package, I remove the ```\newtheorem``` commands.

Comment: @Sigur: It seems this class uses the basic `theorem`  package. Not sure it's compatible.

Comment: @Bernard do you have any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: Maybe try loading  `ntheorem`, which has a syntax close  to `theorem` and defines a  `nonumberplain` theorem style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class predefines several theorem-like environments and a `proof` environment that *requires* an argument.

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Author template for INFORMS Journal on Computing (ijoc)
%% Mirko Janc, Ph.D., INFORMS, mirko.janc@informs.org
%% ver. 0.95, December 2010
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass[ijoc,blindrev]{informs3}
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} % current default for manuscript submission

%%\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII % current default line spacing
%%\DoubleSpacedXII
%%\DoubleSpacedXI

% If hyperref is used, dvi-to-ps driver of choice must be declared as
%   an additional option to the \documentclass. For example
%\documentclass[dvips,ijoc]{informs3}      % if dvips is used
%\documentclass[dvipsone,ijoc]{informs3}   % if dvipsone is used, etc.

% Private macros here (check that there is no clash with the style)

% Natbib setup for author-year style
\usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

%% Setup of theorem styles. Outcomment only one. 
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     % Preferred (Theorem 1, Lemma 1, Theorem 2)
%\TheoremsNumberedByChapter  % (Theorem 1.1, Lema 1.1, Theorem 1.2)

%% Setup of the equation numbering system. Outcomment only one.
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\EquationsNumberedThrough    % Default: (1), (2), ...
%\EquationsNumberedBySection % (1.1), (1.2), ...

% In the reviewing and copyediting stage enter the manuscript number.
%\MANUSCRIPTNO{} % When the article is logged in and DOI assigned to it,
                 %   this manuscript number is no longer necessary

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{theorem}
All natural numbers are interesting.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}{Proof.}
Clearly $0$ is interesting. Suppose there is a number that's not interesting
and call $n$ the minimal such. Then it is the minimal uninteresting number,
so obviously it is interesting.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Note that you *must* add an argument to `\begin{proof}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man! It was literally driving me crazy.